# Creating the link between an SQL table and a form in VB

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have created a data source for a project in visual basic using SQL. Now that I want to use the information in the data source, I need to link/ retrieve the data from the SQL table.

I need the code (in visual basic) which allows me to take information from a table.

I assumed it would be something similar to this:

```
Dim DatabaseConnection as (something like dataset) (File name)
Dim table1 as (I don't know the datatype) (file name)
```

Then be able to access the data in the table like so:

textbox1.text = table1.customerName(2)

I haven't found any decisive help with this issue, many people have said to use queries to extract the data, but I need some basic, commented code that can teach me how to start accessing the data within my data sources.

Any help that you could provide would be very useful!

Comment: Did you try something?

Comment: there are many tutorials about [ADO.Net](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e80y5yhx(v=vs.110).aspx), difficult to believe you didn't find a single one.

Comment: Not that, but I am running out of time regarding the project I need to do :P it might seem impatient but I needed the code to get me going. I did have a look at LINQ though and it has helped to sort the problem out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use code like this:

```
 Dim conn as string ="yourconnectionstring"
 Dim DT as DataTable
 Dim query as string ="select * from mytable"
 Dim command as Sqlcommand = new sqlcommand(query,conn)

 Dim da as new SqlDataAdapter
 DA.selectcommand = command

 da.Fill(DT)

 Textbox1.text=DT.row(0)("column")
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly the kind of code I need!